# calculate average of ArrayList<Float[]> type that returns Float[] in java

Tags: java

I have an `ArrayList` of type `Float[]`, and i am trying to calculate the average of those `Float[]` in the `ArrayList`;
    eg:

```
[1.5,5.5,2.5,3.0,7.5]
[2.5,7.5,4.5,3.5,9.5]
[8.5,5.5,6.5,4.0,1.5]
[5.5,8.5,6.5,2.0,4.5]
```

and want the final return result of

```
[4.5,6.75,5.0,3.125,5.75]][1]
```

Comment: Can you format that as code on your question?

Comment: What have you tried and what are you having trouble with?  Why are you using `Float[]` and not `float[]`? Do you need to allows values to be `null`?

Comment: i was trying to implement k-Mean clustering Algorithm, 
During which, i have to calculate the average of the average from the each cluster.
So, this is just a part of it,
If Code is required, i will paste is here soon,

Comment: @redFIVE, this is not "Please do my work for me" post,
My code does not fit here

Comment: It reads as such when you just post requirements and show no effort and ask no specific question.

Comment: @redFIVE, i can mail you my code, can u inbox me you emailID.

Comment: @redFIVE, when i try to paste my code, it doesn't allow more character to paste.

Comment: @JageshMaharjan code required to make this work shouldn't take up a ton of space.

Comment: @JageshMaharjan, you must be able to present a minimal example of the attempt to solve the problem you having. If the code to do this calculation does not fit, you are doing it wrong.

Comment: The portion of the code:
for (Float[] clusterEntry :cluster1)
        {
            Float[] newCentroid1 = new Float[cols];
            Float[] sumcol = new Float[cols];
            for (int i=0;i<clusterEntry.length;i++)
            {
                sumcol[i] += clusterEntry[i];
            }
        }

Comment: @KevinO, I've post a code in the Answer post, Is this the efficient approach for the ArrayList, Could you please give a analysis for the running time of the code.

Answer (score 0):

```
  Float[] newCluster = new Float[cols];
        for (int i=0; i<cols; i++)
        {
            float sum=0;
            for (int j=0;j<cluster1.size();j++)
            {
//                System.out.println(cluster1.get(j)[i]);
                sum += cluster1.get(j)[i];
            }
            newCluster[i] = sum/cluster1.size();
        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(newCluster));
    }
```

Comment: will C# implementation do the job?

Comment: @Bikee  would appreciate, if in c#.